# Meaning of "he'd been had" in this song

Tags: idiom-meaning, songs

There is a song which starts with

> Juno was mad, he knew he'd been had
> So he shot at the sun with a gun
> ...

But I'm having trouble trying to understand the expression "he knew he'd been had" in this situation... or any situation for that matter. I believe it must be some idiom.

Song is "Ruler of everything" from Tally Hall.

Comment: This is in dictionaries. For example: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/be%20had

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/have) includes the usage **have on** *Try to make someone believe something that is untrue, especially as a joke.* So if you've 'been had' then someone has tricked you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be had usually means to be the object of a con or scam to some degree, to have been a 'mark', a dupe. So your lyric suggests he was  conned and then realised it later .

Comment: Please don't answer questions that have been clearly pointed out to be duplicates.